# SQL error when generated SQL command with Doctrine PHP

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, mysql-error-1054

I use Doctrine on my PHP web application with a MySQL database. I have a little problem with my request :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('event.EventDate, event.EventId, player.PlayerId, player.FirstName, 
             player.LastName, player.Login, player.Email, 
             event_period.EventPeriodId, event.Type, event.Description, 
             period.StartHour, period.EndHour, player_event_period.Participate, 
             event_period.CourtNumber')
     ->from('Event event, Player player, Period period')
     ->leftJoin('player.PlayerEventPeriod player_event_period')
     ->leftJoin('player_event_period.EventPeriod event_period')
     ->where('period.PeriodId = event_period.PeriodId')
     ->andWhere('event.EventId = event_period.EventId');
```

if I show what is the generated MySQL command, I can see

```
SELECT e.eventid AS e__eventid, e.eventdate AS e__eventdate, e.type AS e__type, e.description AS e__description, p.playerid AS p__playerid, p.firstname AS p__firstname, p.lastname AS p__lastname, p.login AS p__login, p.email AS p__email, p2.periodid AS p2__periodid, p2.starthour AS p2__starthour, p2.endhour AS p2__endhour, p3.playereventperiodid AS p3__playereventperiodid, p3.participate AS p3__participate, e2.eventperiodid AS e2__eventperiodid, e2.courtnumber AS e2__courtnumber
FROM event e, player p, period p2
LEFT JOIN player_event_period p3 ON p.playerid = p3.playerid
LEFT JOIN event_period e2 ON p3.eventperiodid = e2.eventperiodid
WHERE (
p2.periodid = e2.periodid
AND e.eventid = e2.eventid
);
```

I get error :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'p.playerid' in 'on clause'
```

What's wrong with my request ?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

If that could help you. I have add the script that creates my database tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `EventId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `EventDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EventId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `event_period` (
  `EventPeriodId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PeriodId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EventId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CourtNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EventPeriodId`),
  KEY `fk_event_period_to_period` (`PeriodId`),
  KEY `fk_event_period_to_event` (`EventId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `period` (
  `PeriodId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StartHour` time NOT NULL,
  `EndHour` time NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PeriodId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `PlayerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Login` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `RankId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `FirstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ValidateId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `InscriptionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Enable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerId`),
  KEY `fk_player_to_rank` (`RankId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `player_event_period` (
  `PlayerEventPeriodId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PlayerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EventPeriodId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Participate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerEventPeriodId`),
  KEY `fk_player_event_period_to_player` (`PlayerId`),
  KEY `fk_player_event_period_to_event_period` (`EventPeriodId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `event_period`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_event_period_to_period` FOREIGN KEY (`PeriodId`) REFERENCES `period` (`PeriodId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_event_period_to_event` FOREIGN KEY (`EventId`) REFERENCES `event` (`EventId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `player`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_player_to_rank` FOREIGN KEY (`RankId`) REFERENCES `rank` (`RankId`);

ALTER TABLE `player_event_period`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_player_event_period_to_player` FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerId`) REFERENCES `player` (`PlayerId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_player_event_period_to_event_period` FOREIGN KEY (`EventPeriodId`) REFERENCES `event_period` (`EventPeriodId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your models look but do your table called "player" have a column called "playerid" in it?

That's what mysql is complaining about.

[Edit] 
I think that Doctrine prefers column names i lowercase.
(Can't remember if MySQL is case-sensitive regarding column names...)

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the script that generate the structure of my tables

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity of MySQL column names depends on how the database/schema/tables are configured, but it looks like yours are case sensitive.

You haven't provided the entity definitions so I'm guessing at the issue, but try setting the name of the column.

For example for player id the annotation would be:

```
/**
 * @Column(name="PlayerId", type="integer", length=11, nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $PlayerId;
```